# Repeatable field not visible anymore?

Tags: joomla-3.x, fields

I need to use the repeatable field, but on a installation thats a but older there is no repeatable field available. Does anyone know how to install this?

Comment: Please be aware that repeatable fields are deprecated and will permanently be removed. Any code your writing now might not work on Joomla 4.
See https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about the repeatable custom field? If so, then you could try the following:

1. Download a copy of the latest Joomla (3.9.26 as of this writing).
2. Go to the folder /plugins/fields.
3. Copy/upload the 'repeatable' map to your Joomla site and add it in the same folder (/plugins/fields).
4. In the backend of your Joomla site go to Extensions > Manage >
   Discover.

That should give you the option to install the repeatable field.